# OpenCv facedetection sample getting stuck without any error or log

Tags: linux, opencv, gcc, face-detection

I am trying to execute facedetect sample of Opencv-2.4.7 on linux environment. But it get stuck without giving any error , warning or log. The strange thing happening is if I try to debug the process using strace then the execution completes with correct output.

I am compiling the facedetect.cpp using following command:

`gcc -o facedetect facedetect.cpp -L/usr/local/opencv-2.4.7/lib
-I/usr/local/opencv-2.4.7/include -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_imgproc
-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui`

and executing it by command as follows:

`/usr/local/opencv-2.4.7/facedetect
--cascade="/usr/local/opencv-2.4.7/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml" image.jpeg`

Any suggestion will be helpful!!

Comment: I suggest a quick and dirty debugging exercise: edit `facedetect.cpp` and put some `cout << "Hello\n";` in different parts of the code to see where you code gets stuck at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to waitkey function call which doesnot respond. Following link can be used for resolving this purpose:

[Opencv python. WaitKey don't respond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539497/opencv-python-waitkey-dont-respond/20540772)

Although in my case it works fine even if I comment the waitkey function call.