# cv2.waitKey(0) not working, OpenCV 3.1.0, Mac OS X 10.11.6, Python 2.7.12

Tags: macos, python-2.7, break, opencv3.0

I have these two statement in the end of my python program:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Somehow cv2.waitKey(0) not working, no response to keyboard input 0, to end my program I had to close my Mac terminal window.

I tried the following to fix the problem

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

then I got this message:
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Not sure what's wrong. I am using a Macbook Air, Mac OS X 10.11.6
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Key must be pressed from image window. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28322925/8864294

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, waitKey(0) does not mean that keyboard input '0' will terminate the program. It means that your program will wait indefinitely for you to press a key before executing the next line of code.

waitKey(30) means that the program will wait for 30 ms for you to press a key, then it'll move on.

as for the `'break' outside loop` error, fundamentally you use 'break' keyword **inside** a 'for' or 'while' loop only to stop looping. So you need to ensure that you're calling 'break' if there are loops involved in your code, like so:

```
while True:
       #do your thing
       if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break #this loop will break if you press 'q', else it'll wait
```

Say there are no loops in your program, then you replace 'break' statement with a 'return' statement

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure without the full code, but 'break' outside loop is probably because of indentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't need any additional methods after waitKey(0)

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Window appears -> Click on the Window & Click on Enter. Window will close.