# opencv cv2.destroyAllWindows() doesnt respond

Tags: python, opencv

I have 64bit, ubuntu system. Im running the code in idel.
I was facing opencv hang issue , the image shows up but I have to force kill the image window. So reffered to this thread -- [Using other keys for the waitKey() function of opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494101/using-other-keys-for-the-waitkey-function-of-opencv)

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('sof.jpg') # load a dummy image
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(3000) & 0xff
    if k==32:    # SpaceBar key to stop
        break
    elif k==-1:  # normally -1 returned,so don't print it
        continue
    else:
        print k # else print its value
```

Still its not working image hangs and I have to close it manually.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you try it from the command line shell instead of from idle? I had problems with idle and GUIs (I think it was tkinter) a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
k = cv2.waitKey(3000) & 0xff
```

Comment: Can u explain a bit ?

Comment: mask out the 'ascii' part from whatever you get there (scankeys?) , so you can check against k==27 or similar

Comment: Its not working. I had to again restart the idle shell to kill the image

Answer (score 0):

Add cv2.waitkey(0) and cv2.destroyallwindows() but If you have used python notebooks then there is a problem in Unix based system to run a program of opencv. It will cause system freeze so you will need to restart kernel everytime when you try to execute code.

I have an alternative method which would prevent from freezing your system

Steps:

1. -Copy the code from python notebooks and create new filename.py and paste it

   - Open terminal
   - cd path/to/file
   - source activate VirtualEnvironment
   - python filename.py

This will run code directly from terminal.
Hope this helps you. 
Example Link: https://youtu.be/8O-FW4Wm10s