# ubuntu: openCV changed key codes

Tags: python, opencv, keyboard, key, ord

I'm working with openCV library in Python and I have very strange behaviour:

I have a code like this:

```
...
img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == ord('p'):
    do_something()
else:
    print key, ord('p')
...
```

When I'm running my code and pressing `p` button, I can see the following:

`1048688 112`

It means that integer representation of `p` button is 1048688, but expected 112.

What is strange yet, this code was working during a few last days, but now it's not working. I haven't any changes in this code.

Any ideas? It it possible that something changed in system?

Comment: 112 in hex is `0x70`. 1048688 in hex is `0x100070`. [Looks like some extra flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494101/using-other-keys-for-the-waitkey-function-of-opencv) are in higher order bits. Just mask that out and use the LSB. According to one of the answer in the question I refer to, the thing that changed in your system is that you pressed NumLock.

Comment: @DanMašek, heh...Nice catch with Numlock. It was really unexpected for me.