# openCV waitkey() is not working for bangla characters

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I'm working on a program (python 2.7.12 ,opencv) in which I am using waitkey to train characters/digits, In my code-

```
result = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

here `cv2.waitkey` works well for all the characters that have got an ASCII value of range 0 to 255 or more(I guess),but when I press any bangla character (i.e অ,ই,উ,ক etc using avro or bijoy keyboard software) instead of these characters '?' is stored in result variable.

And if I check like this- "if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('অ')" it results out-"TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found".How to handle these unichars using waitKey?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here. It seems that you can solve your problems with the help of the `ord()` function: [Using other keys for the waitKey() function of opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494101/using-other-keys-for-the-waitkey-function-of-opencv)

Comment: I've checked this before,it looks good for space,RightKey,DownKey etc but does not even work for any Bangla/Hindi character@Ukimiku