# Is it possible to read unicode value using cv::waitkey(0)

Tags: c++, opencv, unicode, ascii, highgui

I am trying to read the unicode value of a pressed Arabic key using the waitkey() function on a Mac keyboard, this function only reads the ASCII code of the keys in C++.

Is there like any trick that maps that key value ?

Comment: *Is there like any trick that maps that key value* create a mapping by yourself.

Comment: I need it to be able to accept both Arabic and English, by mapping it will always get the Arabic character, how can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14494131/9163420) can help you to print key values. You can test the one that you want and use it inside `waitKey`.