# Create GUI with cv2 python alone

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to create a GUI (create a Button to select an image from directory or list the image from a particular directory and select one image for conversion)with python cv2.Because i can't install pyqt or tkinter like modules.
I have cv2 , numpy and other basic modules.How can i do this without installing any other modules ? (my device have space limitation ).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass key inputs to opencv but [not easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494101/using-other-keys-for-the-waitkey-function-of-opencv#14494131), as well as [log](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) slider events with generic functions. It doesn't look like there is a native file interface even in the latest version (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html)

What about creating a command line GUI? You can use autocomplete in raw input as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input#5638688) and then pass the input to `imread` and then `imshow` the file.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to create an application so i need gui (the application need a key and if i press the key then it open a directory which contain images ,after selecting the image just press another key 'ok' and the image will display and the converted rgb values where shown in background.So i didn't need terminal gui.Is it possible with cv2 module alone in python ?

Comment: Is it possible to create this application with an image of a switch ?

Comment: I posted an answer then deleted as it involved tkinter.  If you can use it, I'll repost the sample program that showed integrating OpenCV with a GUI.

Comment: I'm no expert in OpenCV but it looks like there is no native solution to select files in the OpenCV High-level GUI. If you could use tkinter, the solution is simple (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) or use MikeyB's solution.